# iOS receipt does not include repurchased transaction

Tags: ios, storekit

If I wipe the data in my app, then re-purchase some managed IAP that I know the account already owns, iOS gives me the native "are you sure you wish to repurchase this item you will not be charged" dialog. That's as expected.

When the purchase returns to my app, I get the receipt with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`. I then attempt to verify the SKPaymentTransaction's transactionIdentifier with the receipt via my server.

However the receipt's transaction ID for this IAP, because I've already purchased it long ago, is not the same as the SKPaymentTransaction.

How should I be verifying that this is a valid repurchase? Can I get a signed receipt for this repurchase somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the purchases will be in a single receipt. You do have to check all iAPs there and look for the needed ones.

If you want the id of the original iAP transaction, there is Original Transaction Identifier

> For a transaction that restores a previous transaction, the transaction identifier of the original transaction. Otherwise, identical to the transaction identifier.

More information about receipt fields is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Anyway, does it really matter whether this is an original purchase or a repurchase? My checks of this are usually the same.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it you should check the `originalTransaction` to check that this is valid for transactions that are `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]` is for the receipt of the main application, not the IAP.

Comment: this is good info. you infer there's a receipt for the transaction, but how can I get that? transactionReceipt on SKPaymentTransaction is deprecated.

Comment: The iOS 7+ style local receipt has both app _and_ IAP receipts unified within. The info for local receipt validation -- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html --  (and the various third-party implementations) have the details for iterating over the purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) library, and check all purchases:

```
RMStoreAppReceiptVerificator *verificator = [[RMStoreAppReceiptVerificator alloc] init];

if ([verificator verifyAppReceipt])
{
    NSArray *inAppPurchases = [RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt].inAppPurchases;

    for (RMAppReceiptIAP *inAppPurchase in inAppPurchases)
    {
        NSLog(@"productIdentifier %@ originalPurchaseDate %@", inAppPurchase.productIdentifier, inAppPurchase.originalPurchaseDate);
    }
}
```

If your receipt is nil you can refresh receipt:

```
 [[RMStore defaultStore] refreshReceiptOnSuccess:^{
        //get purchases
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
```